# basic rails api questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api

I'm just starting to learn to build api's in rails and have a question getting started.  I just want to practice creating routes and controllers but can't get this to work

config/routes.rb

```
  namespace :api, :path => "", :defaults => {:format => :json}, :constraints => {:subdomain => "api"} do    
    get '/prac' => 'sessions#prac'
  end
```

controllers/api/sessions_controller.rb

```
def prac
  "hello world"
end
```

When I got to api.localhost:3000/prac,  I get (No route matches [GET] "/prac").  I just want the hello world to show up so that I know I am on the right path.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: mostly this one [link](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2013/06/13/building-awesome-rails-apis-part-1/) but i've been kinda winging it also.

Answer (score 0):

it's the `subdomain` part.

```
subdomain(tld_length = @@tld_length)
```

> Returns all the subdomains as a string, so `"dev.www"` would be returned for “dev.www.rubyonrails.org”. You can specify a different `tld_length`, such as 2 to catch `"www"` instead of `"www.rubyonrails"` in “www.rubyonrails.co.uk”.

In your case, as the subdomain of `api.localhost` is `''`, so this should pass

```
namespace :api, :path => "", :defaults => {:format => :json}, :constraints => {:subdomain => ""} do    
  get '/prac' => 'sessions#prac'
end
```

Or, you can use a normal local host, like `api.local.com` to make your `subdomain` check work.